# Serve static files and app.get conflict using Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have this piece of code here:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(1344);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session){
        console.log(req.session);
    }
    console.log('ok');

});
```

The code inside the `app.get()` callback is not being called. If I comment out the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` line, then the callaback works. I've tried changing the order, but its like a lottery! I would prefer to know whats going wrong here.

I'm sure this have to do with lack of knowledge from my part on how the middleware is called. Can someone help me understand this problem?

Basically I just want to perform some logic before the files are served and the index.html is load on the browser. By the way placing the `app.get()` before the `app.use(express.static())` line, does not did the trick!

Comment: Do you have a public/index.html file?

Comment: That's why it's broken. Remove it and everything will work. There might be an option like "dir" to disable indexes for folders, but I'm not sure

Comment: But, if I remove the index.html file. Which file is going to display. Do I have to rename that same file. Cause I want to render what's in the index.html file.

Comment: Whatever you send in app.get() will be displayed. Right now it's sending index.html then finishing the response, so it never gets to app.get(). I don't know what you're trying to do but using index.html is not a thing in node. Use a templating system.

Comment: Ok. So in order to render the index.html, do I have to send it inside the app.get()? How can I achieve that? Inside publc I have the index.html file which have the css and javascript files define in it. With static I was able to load the index.html and subsequently the rest of the files. Is there another workflow recommended, I am new to Node.js so I could be trying to mimic some PHP habits, and getting everything wrong!

Comment: are none of your pages dynamic? you don't need express if all of your pages are static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your static file middleware should go first.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
```

And you should be adding a use for app.router as well.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(app.router);
```

Middleware is processed in order for each request.  So if you have an `index.html` in your static files then requests for `yourdomain.com/` will never make it to the `app.router` because they will get served by the static file handler.  Delete `index.html` and then that request will flow through to your `app.router`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if use the mddleware on that order using the app.router, then the files are not served. The code inside app.get() is triggered. I want to execute both the file serving and the code inside app.get().

Comment: Static middleware should always be first because you don't need all the middleware above it. For example, parsing cookies, setting up sessions, or user authentication for static assets is pretty stupid.

Comment: Ok... I get it. I'm not doing a correct use of statics files. I starting to realize that. I'm thinkink on delete the index.html file, and render that file from the server side. Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Jonathan is right.  Put your static handler first, but remove the index.html from your static files.

Comment: what if i want to get to the app.router without deleting index.html ? 
is there any possibility  ?

Comment: In some cases it is not possible to rename index.html, such as when using the create-react-app for a react application and you do not want to eject / customize. In this case you can disable directory indexing with option index: false. E.g. app.use(express.static('public', {index: false}));

Answer (score 3):

Rename your index.html file to something else. It is that simple

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session){
        console.log(req.session);
    }
    console.log('ok');
    res.sendfile(new_index_file);
});
```

Comment: But then what about my CSS file link in my HTML file? Sending the HTML file standalone doesn't link the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have 3 options here:

1) Mount your `app.get('/')` route (possibly, using `app.router`) before static middleware, so that they take precedence. Middleware that is mounted first, processes a matching request first.

2) Use a path prefix for your static paths like `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`, so that statics is served from `example.com/static/...`

3) Want to act smart and shoot yourself in the leg? :) Sometimes people use `Accept` headers and content negotiation to serve 2 different content types from the same url in different circumstances. You can make your static middleware check for a specific content type in `Accept` header and process request, only if requests's `Accept` header wants a proper type. Otherwise, it will pass the processing down the stream to you `/` view. You can customise your static middleware content negotiation in [req.accepts](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req).