# express.js: Route Function not called express.js

Tags: node.js, express

My express.js configuration looks like this:

```
//app.js:
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build'), {'index': false}));
app.use('/', routes);

//routes/index.js:
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 console.log("im never called");
});
```

My handler is NEVER called (should be called when requesting without path or just '/'), the browser just gets a 303 with Location //, what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Can you show your full `routes/index.js` file? What are you exporting? Where does `router` come from? Etc. ..

Comment: var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;

there is not more in my index.js. Different routes get called, its just this one route.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `module.exports = router;` to the end of `routes/index.js`

***Edit:***

There is a common practice to put all your static files in one directory (maybe you have done it already) and make all requests to static files start with `/public`:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build'));
```

Doing this way

```
http://yoursite.com/public/some/file.js
```

will be served with

```
../client/build/some/file.js
```

Instead of `/public` you may choose a path that will not intersect with your router.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I already did that. When I remove serving of static files the route is called.

Comment: well its bsaically the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088824/serve-static-files-and-app-get-conflict-using-express-js .. guess I have to rename the index.html or remove it from being served..

Comment: As an alternative, you can put `app.use(express.static...)` after `app.use('/', routes);`

Comment: I tried that, but then my route handler intercept all static requests :/

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue this morning and I thought I would share my solution.

The express.static method is running on all of your requests... when it cannot find a match, it can either run the `next()` function and continue to your desired handler or redirect to a trailing slash to check if the request is for a directory.

I fixed it by adding 'redirect:false' as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(
    path.join(__dirname, '../client/build'), 
    {index: false, redirect: false}));
```

Reference:  [express.static(root, [options])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)