# How to serve React app and Api on same node server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application

I am trying to serve my built react app + api on same server.

I've tried code this :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
    return res.send('pong');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

But whatever url I have in my browser it serves the index.html that is inside the 'build' folder (my react app).  localhost:8080/ping serves the index.html and non 'pong'.

Comment: Is your react app using `react-router` ?

Comment: I had a similar problem due to content-negatiation headers. Use some REST client to check, what headers are being sent in your request and try stripping them - you'll get response from your `/ping` view.

Comment: No router in my react

Comment: Specifically, try to get rid of `Accept` header in your request - I believe, if it is in the request, it is processed by `express.static` middleware, otherwise it will go to your `/ping` view.

Comment: Can you create a url prefix for your static middleware, like `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));` so that it serves files from `example.com/static/...` url or is it supposed to be serving files at root url?

Comment: Your question exaclty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088824/serve-static-files-and-app-get-conflict-using-express-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Serve static files and app.get conflict using Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088824/serve-static-files-and-app-get-conflict-using-express-js)

Rename your index.html file to something else. It is that simple

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session){
        console.log(req.session);
    }
    console.log('ok');
    res.sendfile(new_index_file);
});
```