# How to properly deploy a ReactJS frontend with a NodeJS backend on firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

To learn ReactJS and Firebase, I had create a web app with these technologies.

But I didn't publish this app on the web because, since react is a frontend library, we can see the code with my firebase infos.

Now I have learned NodeJS and I want to implement that on my app for the backend and publish on firebase but I don't know how publish an app with both React *and* Nodejs on firebase.

The only idea I have is to run the `npm build` command, put the content of the `build` folder in a `view` folder of my Nodejs project, and redirect the home page to my React index like that:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('view/index');
});
```

and publish on firebase like a nodeJS project.

I think this is a good solution but I want to be sure and know if a better solution exist because I want to use the best practices, and move the build content after each frontend update... (and I don't want to restart all my backend if I don't know how publish after)

Comment: Your question is kind of too broad, since there are a lot of things you could do, different libs you could use, etc., like [improving your server to handle a React app by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088824/1218980) or automating some kind of build step to move files around.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ok so there are ways to automate but if not, the solution that I propose in my question would work, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not totally clear, but it sounds like you're asking how to use a serverless Firebase function as a back end for your react project.

To do that, you simply create an HTTPS function that serves as an endpoint for your front end to send data to, which is then processed and sent back, or logged, or interacts with a database, etc.

Setting up an HTTPS function is easy: you run `firebase init` in a directory, choose 'functions' when asked what to initialize, and and the CLI will generate The necessary files for your project.

In your index.js file, you write the node.js code for your function, and then run `firebase deploy` from that same directory.

Then your endpoint will be live, and it can consume any requests you send it to it.  For more, see the official documentation on Firebase functions.

. References:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#initialize_a_firebase_project

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: Sorry if is not totally clear, is probably because of my bad english ^^'
So if I use function as you say, I can deploy my nodeJS project on Firebase, but after, how i can deploy my reactJS project without overwriting nodejs files ?

If after finishing my reactJS I build it, I move my build folder to the nodeJS project, and I redirect to the react index (in the nodeJS file) will it work?

Comment: Try a sample at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples nothing gets overridden